# How to show the bottom of a Form when its last component is displayed?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp

The `container` which contains the `components` inside a `Form` has a `TOP` and `BOTTOM` `margin` set to 1 and 10 respectively. The problem is that when scrolling through the navigation button ( the down key ) then when reaching the last component which is a Button then the remaining space below , the bottom margin, is not shown. Here are the image when scrolling to the last component :

[image]
What I want is like this image :

[image]
So how to show the bottom margin space when scrolling the last component ?

Comment: Why you are not using LWUIT 1.5? Any Reason?

Comment: @pheromix, To get required spacing at the top and bottom of first and last component respectively you need to _"add padding to the `container containing these components"`_. Next you duplicate these same padding values for the components container for all states viz `Unselected`, `Selected`, `Pressed` and `Disabled`. Next confirm that first and last component is focusable. Also please refer if relevant [link1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), [link2](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/23/using-styles-themes-painters-with-lwuit.html). Let me know if these helped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using LWUIT 1.5 or SVN then we can't verify and help with issues like these since LWUIT changed quite allot since 1.4.

Comment: But I don't like the `Tabs` component in 1.5 Sometimes its `focusListener` doesn't work !

Comment: I haven't run into that problem myself, if the focus listener doesn't work its a bug and you should file an issue in the LWUIT issue tracker about this at http://lwuit.java.net/